# Getting the number of unique values of a query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have some documents with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id": "53ad76d70ddd13e015c0aed1",
    "action": "login",
    "actor": {
        "name": "John",
        "id": 21337037
    }
}
```

How can I make a query in Node.js that will return the number of the unique actors that have done a specific action. For example if I have a activity stream log, that shows all the actions done by the actors, and a actorscan make a specific action multiple times, how can I get the number of all the unique actors that have done the "login" action. The actors are identified by actor.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[db.collection.distinct()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

```
db.collection.distinct("actor.id", { action: "login"})
```

will return all unique occiriences and then you can get count of a result set.

PS
do not forget about `db.collection.ensureIndex({action: 1})`

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation framework for this:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    /* Filter only actions you're looking for */
    { $match : { action : "login" }},
    /* finally group the documents by actors to calculate the num. of actions */
    { $group : { _id : "$actor", numActions: { $sum : 1 }}}
]);
```

This query will group the documents by the entire actor sub-document and calculate the number of actions by using $sum. The [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator will filter only documents with specific action.

However, that query will work only if your actor sub-documents are the same. You said that you're identifying your actors by `id` field. So if, for some reason, actor sub-documents are not exactly the same, you will have problems with your results.

Consider these these three documents:

```
{
    ...
    "actor": {
        "name": "John",
        "id": 21337037
    }
},
{
    ...
    "actor": {
        "name": "john",
        "id": 21337037
    }
},
{
    ...
    "actor": {
        "surname" : "Nash",
        "name": "John",
        "id": 21337037           
    }
}
```

They will be grouped in three different groups, even though the `id` field is the same.
To overcome this problem, you will need to group by `actor.id`.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    /* Filter only actions you're looking for */
    { $match : { action : "login" }},
    /* finally group the documents to calculate the num. of actions */
    { $group : { _id : "$actor.id", numActions: { $sum : 1 }}}
]);
```

This query will correctly group your documents by looking only at the `actor.id` field.

**Edit**

You didn't specify what driver you were using so I wrote the examples for MongoDB shell.

Aggregation with Node.js driver is very similar but with one difference: Node.js is async The results of the aggregation are returned in the callback. You can check the Node.js [aggregation documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate) for more examples:

So the aggregation command in Node.js will look like this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('auditlogs');

    collection.aggregate([ 
        { $match : { action : "login" }}, 
        { $group : { _id : "$actor.id", numActions: { $sum : 1 }}} ],
        function(err, docs) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            console.log(docs);
            // do something with results
        }
    ); 
});
```

For these test documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b162ea698171cc1677fab8"),
    "action" : "login",
    "actor" : {
        "name" : "John",
        "id" : 21337037
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b162ee698171cc1677fab9"),
    "action" : "login",
    "actor" : {
        "name" : "john",
        "id" : 21337037
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b162f7698171cc1677faba"),
    "action" : "login",
    "actor" : {
        "name" : "john",
        "surname" : "nash",
        "id" : 21337037
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b16319698171cc1677fabb"),
    "action" : "login",
    "actor" : {
        "name" : "foo",
        "id" : 10000
    }
}
```

It will return the following result:

```
[ { _id: 10000, numActions: 1 },
  { _id: 21337037, numActions: 3 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is your answer:

```js
db.actors.aggregate([
    // If you really need to filter
    { "$match": { "action": "login" } },
    // Then group
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "action": "$action",
            "actor": "$actor"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Your "actor" combination is "unique", so all you need to do it have the common "grouping keys" under the `_id` value for the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage and count those "distinct" combinations with [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).